# Compilation C, C++, Objective-C et Objective-C++ on Mac

Tags: objective-c, gcc, compilation, g++

I use CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH environment variable to compile .cpp files and it works fine to find .h files.

But it's not ok to compile ObjC or ObjC++.

Do you know the good one variable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the manual page:

> ```
>    CPATH
>    C_INCLUDE_PATH
>    CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH
>    OBJC_INCLUDE_PATH
>        Each variable’s value is a list of directories separated by a
>        special character, much like PATH, in which to look for header
>        files.  The special character, "PATH_SEPARATOR", is target‐
>        dependent and determined at GCC build time.  For Microsoft Windows‐
>        based targets it is a semicolon, and for almost all other targets
>        it is a colon.
>
>        CPATH specifies a list of directories to be searched as if
>        specified with −I, but after any paths given with −I options on the
>        command line.  This environment variable is used regardless of
>        which language is being preprocessed.
>
>        The remaining environment variables apply only when preprocessing
>        the particular language indicated.  Each specifies a list of
>        directories to be searched as if specified with −isystem, but after
>        any paths given with −isystem options on the command line.
>
>        In all these variables, an empty element instructs the compiler to
>        search its current working directory.  Empty elements can appear at
>        the beginning or end of a path.  For instance, if the value of
>        CPATH is ":/special/include", that has the same effect as
>        −I. −I/special/include.
> ```